# C# Method ceases to function upon adding it to this.Deactivate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application I have two forms: The main window and an Overlay. The overlay can be minimized(by controlling it's size) to the screens top and and the main window can be minimized to taskbar or system tray.

Upon clicking a button on the overlay, it can switch between minimized and not. When clicking this button the main window enter it's `FormWindowSate.Normal`.

I want this to work not just when clicking the control button, but when the overlay lose focus. Hence my problem: If I add the code which hide the overlay to an event handler, I can hide the overlay just fine. But when I try to add the code which return the main window to it's original state, that code cease to function everywhere.
Here is the relevant code:

in the overlay Form:

```
public event System.EventHandler OnShowOverlay;
public event System.EventHandler OnHideOverlay;

private void ShowOverlay()
{
    OnShowOverlay(this, null);
    this.Focus();
    OverlayPanel.Visible = true;
    this.Height = 70;
    this.InfoPanel.Location = new Point(25, 35);
    this.OverlayShowButton.Location = new Point(0, 35);
}
private void HideOverlay()
{
    if(OnHideOverlay != null)
    {
        OnHideOverlay(this, null); //!!!
        this.Focus(); 
        this.OverlayPanel.Visible = false; //***
        this.OverlayShowButton.Location = new Point(0, 0); //***
        this.InfoPanel.Location = new Point(25, 0); //***
        this.Height = 35; //***
    }
}
private void OverlayShowButton_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    OverlayPanel.Visible = !OverlayPanel.Visible;
    if (OverlayPanel.Visible)
    {
        ShowOverlay();
    }
    else
    {
        HideOverlay();
    }
}

public void OverlayNoFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideOverlay(); //!!!
}
```

in the overlay designer:

```
this.Deactivate += new System.EventHandler(OverlayNoFocus);
```

in the main form:

```
public MainForm()
{
    //irrelevant code here.

    this.overlay.OnShowOverlay += new System.EventHandler(onOverlayShow);
    this.overlay.OnHideOverlay += new System.EventHandler(onOverlayHide);
    this.overlay.Show();

    //irrelevant code here.
}

FormWindowState saveWinState = new FormWindowState();
        
void onOverlayShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveWinState = this.WindowState;
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
void onOverlayHide(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = saveWinState;
}
```

//!!! When `OnHideOverlay` is in `OverlayNoFocus`, the problem occur.
//*** These line function as expected so long as `OnHideOverlay` is not in `OverlayNoFocus`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The Visible property is tricky, it doesn't return the value you assigned to it.  Instead it tells you if the panel is actually visible to the user.  The failure mode is not terribly obvious but the WindowState usage is a cue of sorts.  If you ever minimize the overlay form then OverlayPanel.Visible will always return false.  Use a bool instead.

Comment: Thank you, I actually am, though. If you look in the HideOverlay() and ShowOverlay() functions. I did reverse the if statement and remove the assignment based on your suggestion, though.
Sadly though, it doesn't affect my actual problem at hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the app's initial state might consist of a visible `MainForm` where the overlay button is:

> [...] minimized(by controlling it's size) to the screens top.

(I take your word that you literally mean top of the *screen* not just top of the main form.)

[image: overlay-minimized]

---

Clicking [Overlay] causes app to enter a state where the overlay is expanded and the main form might be:

> [...] minimized to taskbar or system tray.

[image: show-overlay-minimize-main]

---

I believe the intention of your question about **this.Deactivated** is that any loss of focus results in a revert to the original state and the overlay should minimize if:

- [Overlay] button is clicked a second time.
- Mouse click occurs outside the client rectangle of overlay form.

My first suggestion is to make the `OverlayForm` autonomous by instantiating it with a reference to the main form. At the same time, I would avoid using the `this` pointer in the `Show()` method because if main form is `Owner` of overlay form then when main form minimizes it takes overlay form down with it! So avoid that.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _overlayForm = new OverlayForm(this);
        _overlayForm.Show(); // Avoid setting owner with 'this'.
    }
    private readonly OverlayForm _overlayForm;
}
```

---

**OverlayForm**

In this scheme of things the messaging is simplified because `OverlayForm` can act upon `MainForm` directly. All the `Deactivate` event has to do is uncheck the `Overlay` button.

```
public partial class OverlayForm : Form
{
    public OverlayForm(Form mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
        _saveWinState = mainForm.WindowState;

        InitializeComponent();
        FormBorderStyle= FormBorderStyle.None;
        BackColor= Color.Azure;
        ShowInTaskbar= false;
        _checkBoxShowOverlay.Appearance = Appearance.Button;

        _checkBoxShowOverlay.CheckedChanged += onCheckedChangedShowOverlay;
        Deactivate += (sender, e) => _checkBoxShowOverlay.Checked = false;

        // Init and give focus back to main form.
        _mainForm.HandleCreated += (sender, e) =>
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => onCheckedChangedShowOverlay(_checkBoxShowOverlay, EventArgs.Empty)));
    }
    private readonly Form _mainForm;
    private void onCheckedChangedShowOverlay(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_checkBoxShowOverlay.Checked)
        {
            Size = _mainForm.Size;
            Location = _mainForm.Location;
            _saveWinState = _mainForm.WindowState;

            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                _mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            Size = new Size(
                _checkBoxShowOverlay.Width + 10,
                _checkBoxShowOverlay.Height + 10);
            Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);
            Location = new Point(
                screen.Bounds.X,
                screen.Bounds.Y);

            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                _mainForm.WindowState = _saveWinState;
                _mainForm?.Activate();
            }));
        }
    }
    FormWindowState _saveWinState;
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful for the time you've put into this! Thank you so much!
Though the basic idea is correct, your code does alternate between the overlay and the main form, I need the code to always display the main form, when it display the overlay and revert back to whatever state it was in before showing the overlay.
I'll give your code some more attention though, when I really understand what you're doing I hope I'll be able to implement the principles you're using! 

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Ok, so the code in the `if (_checkBoxShowOverlay.Checked)` block goes out of its way to minimize the main form so this behavior is easily changed by leaving out that line. I also wasn't 100% sure about the positioning of the expanded overlay, but inferred from the name that it "might" go on top of main form. Also easily modified.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Of course I couldn't implement it line by line, but you helped me understand the basic principle's I needed... 

I think this cut my code down by some 150 lines, since I didn't need custom delegates to catch events on the overlay to call functions on the main form. 

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: It's always the hope in writing an answer that it will be more than a code snippet to copy but rather a new skill for the toolset so it makes it especially worthwhile to know you were able to take it as a starting point and "make it your own" so kudos for doing that!